# A Question about Index Notation of a Scalar Product

Tags: classical-mechanics, velocity, notation

Could anyone please explain why an index $k$ is added to the scalar product of the velocities (squaring the velocity) in the figure below? Can't we use the same index $j$ for the second factor?

> $$\dot{x}_i = \sum^n_{j=1}{\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_j}}\dot{q}_j$$
>   Taking the scalar product of this equation with itself,
>   $$\dot{x}_i^2 = \sum^n_{j=1}\left({\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_j}}\dot{q}_j\right)\cdot\sum^n_{k=1}\left({\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_k}}\dot{q}_k\right)$$

Comment: Technically you could, yes.

Comment: When should I consider taking dummy indices? Is there any general rule for doing so?

Comment: What do you mean by "taking dummy indices"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an arbitrary labelling choice.  You can use $j$ if you want, but to make it clearer that these are two different sums, it's sensible to use a different letter. (e.g. there might be confusion if you were to use $j$ to label two different summations - is that first summation over the sum $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_j}\dot{q}_j\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_j}\dot{q}_j$ or should these terms be separate?)

Note that after you perform the summation, the $k$ and $j$ indices disappear, and you are left with only the $i$ index.  These "dummy" indices can be labelled however you want, because they disappear later.

Comment: I would argue that having the same index actually makes it easier to see they are independent sums, since having a sum within another sum with the same indices is nonsense. But having a sum within another sum with different indices is how you write sums within sums. However, the opposite is true if you were to use Einstein summation notation. Either way, how the parentheses are used helps too.

Comment: Yes the example I wrote is probably a bad example.  If you're careful enough with how you write everything, it shouldn't matter.  Potential problems arise with Einstein summation notation, where the $\sum$ is dropped completely.  As you say, good use of parentheses would help.

Comment: To be more specific. Consider in Chapter 7: Hamilton's Principle, in the Classical Dynamics of Particles and Systems book by Thornton and Marion, Fifth Edition, page 258-259.
Upon squaring Equation (7.117), the authors in the first term of Equation (7.118) are summing over two indices j and k, and not over j only. Can't this change our result? For instance, the Kinetic energy in Equation (7.121) we have now two generalized coordinates because of the two adopted different indices!

Comment: Actually, I am confused whether I should consider k as a dummy index or I should consider curvilinear coordinates and metric tensors as was indicated in the deleted comment!